# printfing a float using %d

Tags: c, printf

I wrote this program with the intentional error in `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        double foo = 2.54f;
        printf("-> %d\n", foo);
}
```

and after running it a few times it ouputs:

-> 1180400440

-> 1754655672

-> 1596232744

-> -905631720

-> 202675976

-> -1580281720

-> 1020283160

-> 929827960

My question is, why does it output a different number every time I run the program?

Comment: `%d` is for `ints`.  `%lf` is for `doubles`.  Read the documentation.

Comment: Also the `f` suffix means "float".  Numbers with a decimal point are doubles by default!

Comment: @abelenky, OP stated it's an "intentional error", so I think he's aware of the correct usage, just curious about why the output is changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because on your platform, `double`s and `int`s are passed to functions differently. Normally, `double`s are passed in floating-point registers, while `int`s are passed in general purpose registers. (Up to some limit, of course; eventually you run out of registers and if there are too many arguments, the remaining ones will be passed on the stack.)

When you tell `printf` to expect an `int`, it looks for the `int` where it expects to find `int`s. But that GPR has not been set to any particular value, because when you called `printf`, you called it with a `double` which was put into a floating point register.

You don't really need to know that, although it might be interesting. It's actually undefined behaviour (UB) to lie to `printf` about the types of the arguments you provide, and most compilers will warn you about that (at least if you provide the `-Wall` command-line option or equivalent). UB means that pretty well anything might happen, including, for example, premature termination of the program or completely random data being used. So make sure you ask the compiler to give you warnings, and make sure you fix them.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, but if **all** arguments were passed on the stack, the output should be the same on each run.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Yes, subject to details like alignment, padding and argument size. In this case, it's reasonable to assume that an `int` is at most as big as a `double`, so if `double` did not require extra padding and all arguments were pushed onto the stack, it's possible that you'd get a consistent output. However, you should *never* write a program which assumes a particular type of Undefined Behaviour (unless you're writing the standard library for a compiler whose internals you're also in control of.)

Answer (score 1):

The error makes your program invokes undefined behavior.

See this C defect report question:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/docs/rr/dr_083.html

Undefined behavior means everything can happen.